# animate.css is not working in Chrome latest version (Version above 73)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

This is the link of animate.css, It doesn't show any animation effect on my browser (Chrome, Firefox etc.)

Comment: Post your code for animation (Html code)

Comment: Do you mind accepting my answer?

Answer (score 19):

The same thing happened to me when I updated my Chrome browser. You need to change the settings under the *Performance Options* of your Windows. To open Performance Options you may search for *Adjust the appearance and performance of windows* or:

1. Windows key + R
2. Enter `%windir%\system32\SystemPropertiesPerformance.exe`

Then change the selected settings to *Adjust for best appearance*.

Comment: Thank You! It's working perfectly.

Comment: if you are prefer "Custom" options , just check the "animate controls..." and "animate windows.."

Comment: txn. worked for me but you can also use 'let windows choose what's best for my computer. this way you have good performance and the animation works.

Answer (score 14):

You have to Adjust the Windows Visual performance settings.

See screenshot. [adjust visual settings windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XK7f0.jpg)

Comment: saved my life, you are a genius!

Comment: For me, the related checkbox was already checked but it needed re-applying for some reason, it's the top most one for future readers

Comment: this is the relevant part in animate.css  :  @media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce), print .  but do not change it much, to keep it comfortable for people with medical need.

Answer (score 11):

From v3.7.0 and up Animate.css supports the prefers-reduced-motion CSS media feature. To disable it you have to remove/comment following in animate.css

```
@media (print), (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
    .animated {
        -webkit-animation-duration: 1ms !important;
        animation-duration: 1ms !important;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 1ms !important;
        transition-duration: 1ms !important;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1 !important;
        animation-iteration-count: 1 !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good ! i just suppress " , (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) " and animate.css work ... 1 hour of research ... Thank you ! - Note:  animations are maybe stupid things but for many clients it's a mark of modernism ...

Answer (score 2):

Fixed since animate.css v3.7.1, more details here: https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/pull/931

Comment: That's fixed, Anyway thank you for your help...The issue was in the " Windows Visual performance settings ". Please look above

Comment: @PrasanthS, changing settings in the "Windows Visual performance settings" was a work-around. I had the same issue on Linux and there's obvisouly no "Windows Visual performance".  The real issue was on how animate.css handled the a reduced motion enviroment. Check github link above for more details.

Comment: actually not working for me on OSX10.12, CHROME 79.0.39 and animate.css 3.7.2
Before chrome update it worked, but i dont know the last version i had

Answer (score 1):

Use `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.0/animate.min.css` css for animation in your code.

This is my code

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.0/animate.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<h2 class="animated slideInLeft" style="animation-delay:1s">Your ultimate Solution</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I already have file of animate.css in my project.So I think its not required to add the CDN right?Anyway I tried with this CDN but it does not work.

Comment: can you paste code over here. so get exactly what is an issue ?

Comment: I don't know what's the issue,the animation in this  js fiddle you provided not working on my browser. Anyway thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Comment/Remove these codes In your * animate.css file - Version - 4.1.1

```
@media print, (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
  .animate__animated {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1ms !important;
    animation-duration: 1ms !important;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1ms !important;
    transition-duration: 1ms !important;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1 !important;
    animation-iteration-count: 1 !important;
  }

  .animate__animated[class*='Out'] {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you download the file you get 3 css files thats for (animate.css,animate.min.css,animate.compact.css)
just copy the animate.compact.css file into your css project folder and then link it dont alter anything this would work..[after your download this is what you should have and the marked one is what i am talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rgo7e.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation of **Animate.css** [here](https://animate.style/#usage) it is said to write class name as follows

> After installing Animate.css, add the class animate__animated to an element, along with any of the animation names (don't forget the animate__ prefix!):

`<h1 class="animate__animated animate__bounce">An animated element</h1>`

So I tried with **animate__animated** but nothing happened.

I found an answer ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56022565/6825364)) where only the **animated**  class name was added and it worked.

- As I understand this is the syntax for version 3 and below

> If you need the old docs - v3.x.x and under - you can find it [here](https://github.com/animate-css/animate.css/tree/a8d92e585b1b302f7749809c3308d5e381f9cb17).

- But somehow I am using version 4 ? - [CDN of Animate.css v4][4]

So the final result that showed the animation is:

`<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css"/> </head><h1 class="animated slideInLeft">Hello World</h1>`

Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

write it in this full form
class="animate__animated animate__swing"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).